# How to calculate value of an analytic function in a closed disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I just have answer of this question which is 6, but I don't know how to arrive at this answer. Please anyone help me solve this. How does one calculate the value of this function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cauchy integral formula or the Cauchy estimate? It can be shown that $|(e^f)''(0)|$ must be less than $2e$ using this method. Let me know if you aren't sure and I can elaborate.

Comment: @Braindead yes sir,I am familiar with Cauchy Integral Formula and with help of this I got my answer also. And thankx sir for giving time to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(z) = \exp(f(z))$. By Cauchy's integral formula,
$$
g''(0) = \frac{2!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{g(z)}{z^{3}}\,dz
$$
so by the "ML"-inequality and the estimate $|g(z)| \le e$, we have
$$
|g''(0)| \le \frac{2!}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi \max_{|z|=1} \frac{g(z)}{z^{3}} \le 2e.
$$

In particular, $|g''(0)| < 6$. (All the other options are smaller in modulus than $2e$.)

Comment: Nice! Also thanks for clearing up my earlier misreading of the question.

Comment: @mrf thankx sir, now my doubt regarding this type of problem is clear.